# My textarea won't accept any width attributes

Tags: html, css, textarea

for some odd reason the text area I have in my site won't accept the width I tell it to, I've tried to select it three times in the `CSS` just to make sure!

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbU4V/) example that shows what I want, and [here is the page](http://www.euroworker.no/Target-7050CC-Duo-UNC.7) where it doesn't want to work. I have searched through the `CSS` to find any conflicting `textarea` properties, but there are none.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:** If you have Firebug, don't forget about it, and use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of your CSS files, you specified `textarea { min-width: 40em; }`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't specify that but it was there, time to talk to some colleagues. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! I picked that up real quick only with Firebug (a Firefox addon letting you inspect CSS/DOM/JavaScript) - it's really useful.

Comment: Yeah, I have that too, should have used it!

Answer (score 2):

You have `min-width: 40em` for all `textarea` elements.